# Adjusting water heater that provides both domestic hot water and baseboard heat

Tags: water-heater, boiler, tankless

I live in an apartment building with in-unit water heaters. Mine is a Weil-McClain Gold CGt gas-fired water boiler with tankless heater. It heats water for domestic use and also for my baseboard radiators. I have the classic tankless shower problem: unless I run a nearby tap, I'm not demanding enough hot water for the demand water heater to stay on. I have a showerhead which purports to be 2.5gpm but it's clearly underperforming, so I'll replace that and see if performance improves.

In the meantime, I'm researching other options. I understand that lowering the set point to 120F or so (hot tap is currently 140F according to my kitchen thermometer) would change the ratio of hot and cold water I'm mixing in the shower, possibly adding enough demand from the water heater to keep it going while I shower. Seems straightforward enough. However, I'm not sure if/how that would affect my baseboard radiators. I have [the boiler manual](https://www.weil-mclain.com/sites/default/files/field-file/cgt-boiler-manual-series-1.pdf) but have so far been unable to understand whether changing the set point would change how my radiators perform. I also found [the user information manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/855863/Weil-Mclain-Gold-Cgt.html?page=5#manual) which has this note:

> **Tankless water heater**
> If boiler is used to supply domestic hot water, limit control should be set to supply adequate hot water. Weil-McLain tankless heaters are rated at 200°F boiler water temperature. To get rated output, set low limit at 200°F. Limit can be adjusted to meet system hot water requirements. Lowering the setting will cause a slight variation in water temperature but will decrease burner on-off cycling. High limit should be set at least 20° above low limit.

Seems to me that this indicates that the tankless heater operates somewhat separately from the radiator system's water circuit. Can anyone confirm I'm on the right track?

Comment: More information is needed to get started. What part of the world are you located in. How cold does it get in the winter.

Comment: @Gil I'm in New York City, where we hover in the 20s and 30s Fahrenheit in winter. Might get down to the teens at night sometimes. Building is ca. 2009. Water heater is about a year old.

Comment: My son had a similar problem in Michigan a few years back. He wound up putting in a hot water heater, at that time you could get them to operate about 160, that is where he said he set his. It worked nicely but you had to be careful taking a shower. On sub -10 days he could not take a shower or do laundry, there was not enough hot water. At this point try a lower setting, I believe as you stated that may force enough water through the heater.